# css element positioning messed up when using php include

Tags: php, css, include

I'm trying to use my main index.php file and to load it with html content and text from other php files (header.php, content.php and footer.php) using "include".

However when I load index.php into my browser, my css positioning of elements is all messed up.
Elements from other files overlap. They just do not position the way I intended them to in my css.
I've tryed to google the solution but didn't have luck finding it.
Can someone direct me to some online reference or tell how does the positioning of elements work when i use include in php?
Thank you in advance.

edit/adding the code:
Index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include './views/header_view.php';
include '/views/sadrzaj_view.php';
include '/views/footer_view.php';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

header file goes like this>

```
<div id="header" >
    <a id="logo"  onmouseover="document.getElementById('logo').style.color='#D0D0D0';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('logo').style.color='#ffffff';">LOGO</a>

</div>
```

content file contains only text for now...

footer file goes like this>

```
<center>
<div id="footer"> 
    123 footer
</div></center>
```

and CSS goes like this>

```
body{
border:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position:relative;
background-image:url(slike/blue_circuit.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;

}


#header{
position:absolute;
background-image:url(./slike/header_bckgnd.png);
border-bottom:1px solid black;

top:0;
height:70;
width:100%;

color:white;
font-family:helvetica;
}



#logo{
position:relative;
left:30;
top:10;
font-size:45;
font-weight:600;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 9px #1E90FF;
cursor:pointer;

}




#footer{

position:fixed;
background-image:url(slike/header_bckgnd.png);
bottom:0;
height:30;

color:white;
line-height:2em;
border:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;

}
```

And the footer overlaps the content part in my IE browser. If I use absolute or relative positioning it doesn't get better... :(

Comment: PHP shouldn't have any baring on CSS. It will be hard to help, though, without any sort of code.

Comment: `include` does not have any direct affect on the positioning of elements. What's being __included__ could, however. Post some code and narrow down a specific problem (What element is it? Where should it be?)

Comment: A PHP include should not be interfering with your CSS. The issue is probably with some markup you have in the included file. Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Well in my index.php the only segment of code (beside <html> and <body> tags) is <?php
include './views/header_view.php';

include '/views/sadrzaj_view.php';
include '/views/footer_view.php';
?>

Included are <div> and some text...

Comment: I have footer div wich doesn't respond to position:fixed; bottom:0; within my css... I can paste here all of my code, but there is nothing more than this that can effect the elemeent positioning... I hoped that include somehow effects the elemenets when being loaded into index.php

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to yours and after some narrowing down I found out that one of my include files (which was purely php) had an echo statement at the bottom which caused my css to somehow scramble(It seemed as if the divs where in absolute position). Anyway, I hope this can help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

go to your output file and examine the markup to see if there are conflicts. 
 I would make a html file from this output and open it up on your browser, it might give you some clues as to whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

place your css at the end of the body tag on your index.php

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and eventually realized that the part I copied into my require() statement from old html files (thinking it was universal for all pages) was actually coded slightly differently for the home page. Thus, when I copied the html from the index file and used it in a require statement for all pages, it caused improper positioning to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post after running into the same issue. Suddenly dawned on me what was going on. Indeed, switching to a PHP include should have no bearing on the CSS positioning. The cause of my error is where I *placed* the PHP include. I was replacing navigation that didn't have absolute positioning, so the include had to be placed in the SAME spot.